# Possible Bug in the 2.0.0 webclient

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When downloading the packed server version of Neo4j community v2.0.0, they provide a web interface for Cypher, however, I cannot make it accept queries of the form:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: {value1}})
RETURN a;
```

It calls a syntax error on the first curly bracket, and will only accept

```
MATCH (a:Person)
WHERE a.name ="value1"
RETURN a;
```

Am I using it wrong, or is this a bug in the parser? The first form appears to work fine when you use it with an embedded client, it is only when using the webclient interface that there is a problem.

UPDATE: To be clear, in the 2.0.0 web interface, even the examples from the Cypher 2.0 reference card throw syntax errors; e.g. the line 
    MATCH (n {name:'Alice'})-->(m)
    RETURN n
from the reference card: http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ gives the following error:

```
Node properties cannot be specified in this context (line 1, column 10)
"MATCH (n {name:'Alice'})-->(m)"
```

even though it works fine when passed to the cypher execution engine in the embedded client.

ANSWER: It turned out the problem was that I was using a milestone release which was not complete/bug free. 2.0.1 stable release solves this problem.

Comment: Are you using a development release of Neo4j, say 2.0-M05 or 2.0-M06?

Comment: It turned out I was, thanks. This was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: It turned out the problem was that I was using a milestone release which was not complete/bug free. 2.0.1 stable release solves this problem. Thanks to jjaderberg.

Answer (score 1):

The notation of your first query is using parameterized Cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html. Parameters are important when developing an application using Neo4j. For usage inside the Neo4j browser, parameters are pretty much useless as you cannot specify the values.

Use the following syntax instead:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: 'value1'})
RETURN a;
```

Comment: It may be unusual, but I don't agree that it's useless :-) You can use the HTTP methods in browser and shell to send cypher with params, `:POST` in browser and `POST` in shell. In shell you can also export the parameters and then use them directly in a query, i.e. `export name="Phil"` and `MATCH (n {name:{name}}) RETURN n;`

Comment: Agreed. Useless in a sense of "when typing cypher in the input box at the top you cannot use parameters". Using `:POST` is a more advanced command.

Comment: The syntax that you give in your answer also fails.